# How to select all list options from drop downlist loop through them selcet each option and click submit button using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the link to print name and meaning columns of all pages using drop down

Try to build the script for following:
1. Go to http://babynames.merschat.com/index.cgi?function=Search&origin=Sanskrit&gender=f
2. print the name and meaning columns to syso.

I was able to print page 1 as it is a default page.
Here is the code:

public class BabyNamesAndMeanings {

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    driver.get("http://babynames.merschat.com/index.cgi?function=Search&origin=Sanskrit&gender=f");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@Test
public void printBabyNamesAndMeaningsOfFirstPage() {
    WebElement baby_names = driver
            .findElement(By
                    .xpath("//tbody/tr[7]/td[3]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/font/table[1]/tbody"));

    List<WebElement> names = baby_names.findElements(By
            .xpath("//tr/td[1]/font/a"));
    List<WebElement> meanings = baby_names.findElements(By
            .xpath("//tr/td[4]/font/a"));

    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println("Name: " + names.get(i).getText()
                + " Meaning:  " + meanings.get(i).getText());
    }

}
```

I don't know how to loop through rest of the options in the drop down list at the bottom of the page and hit submit button to print name and meaning of all the pages.
There are 100+ pages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework. What have you tried and what specifically isn't working? Please give examples of what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will do your job.

```
driver.get("http://babynames.merschat.com/index.cgi?function=Search&origin=Sanskrit&gender=f");
List<WebElement> pageOptions = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='page']"))).getOptions();//Get all options in dropdown
ArrayList<String> pageDd = new ArrayList<String>();
for(WebElement eachPage:pageOptions){
    pageDd.add(eachPage.getText());//Save text of each option
}
int i=1;
for(String eachVal:pageDd){
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='page']"))).selectByVisibleText(eachVal);//Select page
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Go']")).click();//Click on go
    List<WebElement> names = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@title,' meanings and popularity')]"));//Get all names on page
    for(WebElement eachName:names){
        String name = eachName.getText(); //Get each name's text
        WebElement mean = eachName.findElement(By.xpath("./../../..//a[contains(@title,'Names for baby with meanings like ')]"));//Get meaning for that name
        String meaning = mean.getText();//Get text of meaning
        System.out.println(i+") Name: " +name+ " Meaning:  " + meaning);//Print the data
        i++;
    }
}
```

Try and understand the way requirement is achieved. If you have any doubt ask.

Comment: Happy to have been of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Another method to iterate and select all the Dropdown values

```
Select dropdown= new Select(WebUIDriver.webDr.findElement(By.xpath("enter xpath")));
int noOfDropDownValues=  dropdown.getOptions().size()-1;

for(int i=0;i<noOfDropDownValues;i++){
    new Select(WebUIDriver.webDr.findElement(By.xpath("Enter Xpath']"))).selectByValue(String.valueOf(i));
}
```